# On Button Click Validate The Radio Button Group in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="A" GroupName="rbn" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="B" GroupName="rbn" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="C" GroupName="rbn"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="D" GroupName="rbn"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

On Click Button `Validate` it Should Validate The Radio Button group `rbn` and shows the Checked Radio Button Text in `Label1`.

This Should Done In C#. Pls Don't Use any Script's and for loop.

Help Me Out Of this Problem and Thanks In Advance

Comment: -1 for not demonstrating what you've already tried and capitalizing the first letter of every word.

Comment: @DeeMac Sir this is my first try

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RadioButtonList` instead `RadioButton`. To validate `RadioButtonList` use build-in validation control `RequiredFieldValidator` to validate the entire list.

`.aspx`

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatColumns="2"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1" Text="Required">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

`.aspx.cs:`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Label1.Text = "You selected: ";  
    Label1.Text += RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();  
}
```

NOTE: `RequiredFieldValidator` must be at `RadioButtonList` (instead of each ListItem).

**UPDATE:**

As you need `RadioButtons` instead `RadioButtonList`, try this:

`HTML`

```
<input type="radio" value="A" name="radiodbtn" runat="server" /> A
<input type="radio" value="B" name="radiodbtn" runat="server" /> B
<input type="radio" value="C" name="radiodbtn" runat="server" /> C
<input type="radio" value="D" name="radiodbtn" runat="server" /> D

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="validateCheckBoxes" EnableClientScript="true" 
OnServerValidate="validateCheckBoxes_ServerValidate" 
OnClientValidate="validateCheckBoxes_ClientValidate">Required</asp:CustomValidator>
```

then add Javascript for clientside validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e) 
{ 
    e.IsValid = $("input[name='radiodbtn']").is(':checked'); 
} 
</script>
```

now adding server-side validation:

```
protected void validateCheckBoxes_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e) 
{ 
e.IsValid = RadioButton1.Checked || RadioButton2.Checked || RadioButton3.Checked || RadioButton4.Checked;
if(e.IsValid)
{
// at least any one radio button is checked among all group
}
else
{
// no radio button is checked among all group
}
```

Comment: @Selva: sorry, i forgot to remove `ValidationGroup="rbn"` from elements. Now all is set(answer is updated), now it should work! Let me know if not.

Comment: sir i said, it should not in the radio button list sir.

Comment: If i am using 100 radio buttons iwant to type for 100 radio button.checked, is this is the right way analyze and tell the answer sir

Comment: @MM Tac:    Selva is asking about without using neither if else condition nor radio list button. So pls verify your answer and post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RadioButtonList instead of Radiobutton Group. Here is the sample code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbList" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Option1" Value="A" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem> // Selected attribute is used to select a default value
<asp:ListItem Text="Option2" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

in Code Behind

```
protected void btnGetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string OptionName = rbList.SelectedValue;
}
```

You'll get the selected option value into OptionName variable

Comment: if u don't need list item, then you should use if else condition to know which radiobutton is checked. But I recommend to use RadioButtoList